# HTML SVG Line and applying transition to change in x1 y1 attributes in javascript

Tags: svg, line, transition

I have an SVG Line which after 5 seconds receives new x1 y1 coorindates.  How do apply a transition to the line so that it smoothly  moves.  In the code attached, I'm able to change it's color through a smooth transition, but the location blinks from one spot to the other.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
         setInterval(function trackuser ()
        {
            var x_one = 45;
            var y_one = 13;
            var r_one = 50;
            var x_two = 55;
            var y_two = 85;
            var r_two = 36;
            var x_thr = 70;
            var y_thr = 35;
            var r_thr = 28;

            var first = (-Math.pow(x_two,2)+Math.pow(x_thr,2)-Math.pow(y_two,2)+Math.pow(y_thr,2)+Math.pow(r_two,2)-Math.pow(r_thr,2))/(-2*y_two+2*y_thr);
            var secon = (-Math.pow(x_one,2)+Math.pow(x_two,2)-Math.pow(y_one,2)+Math.pow(y_two,2)+Math.pow(r_one,2)-Math.pow(r_two,2))/(-2*y_one+2*y_two);
            var third = ((2*x_one-2*x_two)/(-2*y_one+2*y_two))-((2*x_two-2*x_thr)/(-2*y_two+2*y_thr));
            var x = (first-secon)/third;
            var y = ((2*x_one-2*x_two)/(-2*y_one+2*y_two))*x+secon;

            document.getElementById("line").setAttribute("x2", x+'%');
            document.getElementById("line").setAttribute("y2", y+'%');
            document.getElementById("line").style.stroke = "blue";
            document.getElementById("line").style.WebkitTransition = "all 2s";     // Code for Safari 3.1 to 6.0
            document.getElementById("line").style.transition = "all 2s";       // Standard syntax
        },5000);
    </script>
    <div>
        <svg height="100%" width="100%" style="position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%">
            <line id="line" x1="45%" y1="13%" x2="55%" y2="70%" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:3"></line>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't (yet) animate coordinates with CSS.  You are going to have to animate them yourself with JS.  Either manually (eg. with requestAnimationFrame, or a Timeout), or use one of the SVG javascript libraries.